# Incorrect Syntax error on a duplicate code from an already functioning original code

Tags: vb.net

This project should have been a simple one. Just a web page that loads data from my SQL query into a GridView.

I already have a pre-existing page I done a few years back so a simple copy-paste with modifications to the SQL or defined names should have been fine.

```
Protected Sub loadData()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dsgroup As New DataSet

    Dim string1 As String = "WITH CTE AS (SELECT [Project], [Machine], [Category]," _
                            & "date  + ' ' + time as [DateTime], [Details], [Status]," _
                            & "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Project] ORDER BY (date  + ' ' + time) DESC) AS rn" _
                            & "FROM([SQL].[dbo].[ZMAC]))" _
                            & "SELECT [Project], [Machine], [Category], [DateTime],  [Details], [Status] " _
                            & "FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1"

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(string1, conn) 'declared in seperate config file

    cmd.Connection = conn

    conn.Open()
    da.Fill(dsgroup, "Display")

    Dim dvgroup As DataView = dsgroup.Tables("Display").DefaultView

    GridView1.DataSource = dvgroup
    GridView1.DataBind()

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

And yet when I tested the page I get a syntax error on code portion:

```
da.Fill(dsgroup, "Display")
```

Syntax error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

I even double tested the original web page and it still works all this time.

Why only now when I copy to a new project do I have this issue?

Comment: We have to see `"[MY SQL CODE HERE]"`

Comment: How many times have we seen a question where people are told that they have a syntax error in their SQL code but they haven't bothered to look at their SQL code? The VB code that builds your SQL code is not your SQL code. If there's a syntax error in your SQL, look at the SQL. If you had done that here then the issue would be obvious. This is also a perfect example of why you should NOT use lots of concatenation operators. If you want to write SQL in VB, use a multiline `String` literal or an XML literal. Then you can't make the silly mistake you have here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no white space or control characters between these two lines:

```
& "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Project] ORDER BY (date  + ' ' + time) DESC) AS rn" _
& "FROM([SQL].[dbo].[ZMAC]))" _
```

The resulting string will include this snippet:

```
As rnFROM(
```

and since `rnFROM` is still a perfectly valid alias name, the `(` character from the error message is the first place where the syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer, but there are a few other mistakes in the `LoadData()` method you should address, and I need the code formatting in the answer box to show it.

```
Protected Sub loadData()
    Dim dsgroup As New DataSet
    Dim string1 As String = "[MY SQL CODE HERE]"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(string1, conn) 
        da.Fill(dsgroup, "Display")
    End Using

    Dim dvgroup As DataView = dsgroup.Tables("Display").DefaultView
    GridView1.DataSource = dvgroup
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

What changed:

You should create a **new SqlConnection** for most queries. Really. Trying to re-use the same "conn" variable throughout your application will interfere with ADO.Net's connection pooling and force a bottleneck on that one connection, where otherwise some things might be able to run asynchronously.

Connections should generally live inside a `Using` block, to prevent accidentally leaking open connections if an exception is thrown.

Aside from exceptions, the `Fill()` method will handling opening and closing the connection for you.

The SqlDataAdapter constructor already creates the SqlCommand object you need.

When all is said and done, I cut the size of the method almost in half, reduced memory use, and closed a potential denial of service bug.

But we can do even better. Now I'll move away from fixing actual bugs and more into stylistic improvements. Let's separate the concerns of retrieving the data and updating the screen. Also better to write method that accept an SQL input and return a value. While we're at it, we can enforce correct handling of the SqlConnection by pushing the database stuff into it's own class or module. The result will look like this:

```
Public Module DB
    Private connectionString As String = "..."

    'Keep this PRIVATE
    Private Function GetData(SQL As String, parameters As IEnumerable(Of SqlParameter)) As DataTable
        Dim result As New DataTable
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString), _
              cmd As New SqlComman(SQL, conn)

            If parameters IsNot Nothing Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray())
            End If

            Using rdr AS SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                result.Load(rdr)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    'Separate Public method for each query
    Public Function LoadZMAC() As DataTable
         Dim sql As String = "
             WITH CTE AS (
                 SELECT [Project], [Machine], [Category],
                      date  + ' ' + time as [DateTime], [Details], [Status],
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Project] ORDER BY (date  + ' ' + time) DESC) AS rn
                  FROM [SQL].[dbo].[ZMAC]
              ) 
              SELECT [Project], [Machine], [Category], [DateTime], [Details], [Status]
              FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1"

        Return GetData(sql, Nothing)
    End Function
End Module

Protected Sub loadData()
    'actual database access elsewhere are simple function calls.
    Dim data As Datatable = DB.LoadZMAC()
    GridView1.DataSource = data.DefaultView
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

As an aside, making these changes **WILL** fix the issue in the original question, because I also updated the SQL string to make use of modern multiline string literals as a matter of course, which is where the original problem was. The lesson here is the newer, modern coding styles exist for good reasons. Learning them *will* help you fix or avoid bugs.